# Modification of HTML mail template

Tags: 8, theming, emails

I am using HTML Mail module. I have created an html email template specific to my form(webform) in the template folder of my theme directory. My form name is newsletter and the template name is `htmlmail--webform--newsletter_email.html.twig`

I want to override the email body based on a particular language. But my problem is that `hook_mail_alter` doesn't work in my case.

Drupal API documentation for  `hook_mail_alter` says that `hook_mail_alter()` allows modification of email messages created and sent with `MailManagerInterface->mail()`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The hook `hook_mail_alter()` should work in this case.

Have you double checked if your module is activated and you have cleared your cache after adding the hook?

Also i am not sure if your template will work, because normally all templates are working with dashes instead of underscores.

Comment: Yes did everything. But it didn't work. Also template is working. I already checked that.